# memcpy() to move the contents of an array of structures

Tags: c, memcpy

I am trying to move the contents of an array of structures.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef struct {
      char texts[1024];
}text_i;
text_i textlist[5];
int main()
{
int ind;
strcpy( textlist[0].texts, "hello .."); 
strcpy( textlist[1].texts, "world .."); 
printf("texts before memcpy\n");
for (ind = 0; ind < 5 ; ind++)
        printf("texts ind(%d) is %s \n", ind, textlist[ind].texts);
memcpy( &textlist[1], &textlist[0], 4 * sizeof(text_i));
printf("texts after memcpy\n");
for (ind = 0; ind < 5 ; ind++)
        printf("texts ind(%d) is %s \n", ind, textlist[ind].texts);
}
```

This prints the whole list of 5 `texts` to the string `hello ..`.

```
texts before memcpy
texts ind(0) is hello ..
texts ind(1) is world ..
texts ind(2) is
texts ind(3) is
texts ind(4) is
texts after memcpy
texts ind(0) is hello ..
texts ind(1) is hello ..
texts ind(2) is hello ..
texts ind(3) is hello ..
texts ind(4) is hello ..
```

My intention was to move the textlist[0] to textlist[1] , textlist[1] to textlist[2] , textlist[2] to textlist[3] and so on.

expected:

```
texts ind(0) is hello ..
texts ind(1) is hello ..
texts ind(2) is world ..
texts ind(3) is 
texts ind(4) is
```

I dont want `ind(3)` and `ind(4)` not to be touched. What could be done get it in the above format?

Comment: I think you're using C, not C++? Can you remove one of the tags on your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`memcpy()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) to copy between overwrapped regions invokes *undefined behavior*. Use [`memmove()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memmove) instead.